# php variable into jquery hide function

Tags: php, jquery, html, hide

Could someone help please

Igot something like

```
<div class="hidearea<?php echo $number?>">Example text Example text Example text Example text Example text </div>
<script> $( '.hidearea<?php echo $number?>' ).hide();  </script>
```

How to insert class from div  into hide function as ?

Comment: do it on document ready

Comment: @SHIN Since his script is after the element, it should work as is.

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you wrote? I think it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $( '.hidearea<?php echo $number; ?>' ).hide();
               // And don't forget ^ both times
});
```

**NOTE:** Shouldn't that be an ID instead of a CLASS?
**NOTE 2:** Can't you just set `display: none` in your stylesheet?

Let me know if it's useful

Answer (score 1):

do some thing like this

```
$(function() {
    $( '.hidearea<?php echo $number?>' ).hide();
});

</script>
```